# Who is Laura, and why is she changing so many posts? (An introduction)

Tags: discussion

My name is Laura (which you probably figured out on your own), and I'm a CHAOS ninja at Stack Exchange. I'll be hanging around here on the Photography SE for the next couple of days, editing posts to make them look pretty and sound nice so new users have a good first impression.

Specifically, I'll be editing questions for grammar, spelling, punctuation, and clarity. While I'll be making changes directly to the posts, if you disagree with one of my edits, go ahead and change it back. I'm working standardize and improve the questions, but I trust the judgement of more experienced users. The questions here tend to be really good, so I may not make many changes anyway. :)

Comment: Good gracious...I *just* thought this exact thing and was coming to meta to check on something else and here's the answer.  Craziness ;)

Comment: Its @mattdm's female alter-ego. ;) Welcome aboard, Laura. We do try to keep a clean house...and we appreciate the additional help.

Comment: Hello, nice to see you here! :)

Comment: Thanks for the welcome! Please feel free to let me know if you have feedback on any of my edits you stumble across, or if there are editing/quality issues that you feel are recurring problems. I'm here to help.

Comment: I'd be interested to know generally if you've got any criteria you're going off of.  So that the community can assume the role with the same consistency once you move on to bigger and better things.

Comment: @rfusca CHAOS is new, so we're still deciding on specifics of some of the things we're doing. At the moment, I'm only looking at question titles, and the simple goal is to make sure every title has Good English. We want to make the site approachable to new users, which means making the questions as clear and detailed as possible without distracting users from our awesome content because of typos, weird capitalization, poor grammar, etc. In some cases, I expand titles so that you actually know what the question is, and in others, I shorten titles to just the most important info.

Comment: For example, this question http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/3843/do-lightroom-and-aperture-change-folder-structures-when-you-make-global-edits originally had a title that just said "Lightroom vs. Aperture." The question was specifically about whether either of these apps changes folder structures when you do batch edits, so I changed the title to reflect that.

Comment: But if you're looking for a simple summary of the criteria, we want questions that are complete sentences with good grammar, spelling, and punctuation, and which also accurately reflect the main point of the question.

Comment: My english sucks a lot, so welcome to the community and feel free to make my questions more fancier!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For those looking for a little more info about what CHAOS is and what our mission is, our overlord Joel Spolsky just did [a little write-up](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100137/what-is-the-meaning-of-chaos-is-it-related-to-the-psi-character) (complete with photo of us hard at work).

Comment: And for those wondering why the link doesn't work, [a little info is available here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/257699/241697).